# Need an app that gives the name of organic compounds "step by step"

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I need an app that gives the IUPAC names for any organic compound, and also gives the reasons of this nomenclature, step by step. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to learn how to name organic compounds. It´s not so hard, if you have a proper textbook.

Answer (score 3):

This answer reflects a personal opinion and equally assumes you are student.

ACD's ChemSketch for Windows offers an Academic Version [here](https://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/chemsketch/) which limits the «structure to name» algorithm to 50 heavy atoms (the most typically found in ochem) and three cycles.  Despite this numeric limitation, it equally covers heterocyclic chemistry, too:

[image]

After drawing and selecting the molecule, the GUI entry is found /via/ Tools -> Generate -> Name or the short-cut `Ctrl + Shift + I`. 
Based on your «step by step», I *speculate* this could provide you an entry.  I recommend to use this program with its companion site, a searchable, dictionary-like documentation about the underlying rules ([here](https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/)); start with a simpler core motif which is known to you (e.g., furan), and which step-by-step is modified e.g., by a chain, by stereochemical informations as in the example of of the furanethanol.  The freely available [Marvin sketch](https://chemaxon.com/products/marvin) equally offers a plugin to convert structures to name.

Speaking of heterocyclic chemistry, the nomenclature here requires some additional training because of the side-by-side of «trivial» non-systematic names which may be used as a root, the a-nomenclature, and the systematic Hantzsch-Widman system.  As far I am aware, only [Chemdoodle](https://www.chemdoodle.com/) allows you to instruct the program which set of rules should be used; available only in the paid version.  For example, to name the silicon analogue of thiophene either $1H$-Silole, or Sila-2,4-cyclopentadiene.

Don't overly rely on these programs, though.  If you read the rules and literature, for example, you will find out that 1H-pyrrole *is possible*, but in cases without ambiguity called pyrrole only.